# Реализация проксирования соединения между двумя веб-серверами

Tags: apache, веб-сервер

Есть задача, проксировать соединение с http://centerix.ru/wiki/ на http://wiki.centerix.ru/ .  На centerix.ru стоит Apache, на втором самописный StormServer.

Задача была решена через настройки апача ProxyRequests On и ProxyPass /wiki/ http://wiki.centerix.ru/wiki/ .

Но встала другая проблема, апач присылает на шторм заголовки X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4, X-Forwarded-Host: centerix.ru, X-Forwarded-Server: centerix.ru. Как реализуется проверка, после которой этим заголовкам можно доверять? Как настроить апач, если проксирование будет идти в обратную сторону?

Так же возникает вопрос безопасности данных. Если считать, что оба сервера Apache, то можно ли и как, создав для них самоподписанные ssl сертификаты и настроить так, чтобы все общение между серверами шло по протоколу https?

В принципе, мне требуется понять, какими опциями настраивается апач, после чего я смогу реализовать подобные опции на своем сервере.

Comment: требуется именно проксирование и выдача клиенту редиректа не подходит?

Comment: редирект требует свободный 80 порт, это достаточно дорогое удовольствие.

Comment: я не понял вашего ответа, поэтому предполагаю, что вы не поняли моего вопроса. я предлагаю при обращении к `http://centerix.ru/wiki/somepage` возвращать клиенту 302-й код и адрес `http://wiki.centerix.ru/wiki/somepage`, по которому он и должен обратиться.

Comment: Я понял вопрос. Если мне потребуется освободить 80 порт на wiki.centerix.ru, и я запущу сервер например на порту 8080. То, вы предлагаете редиректить пользователей на http://wiki.centerix.ru:8080/wiki/somepage ? Это довольно корявое решение. А хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь видел сайт как нечто цельное, пусть даже у него каждая директория обрабатывается своим сервером.

Answer (score 2):

в результате просмотра ответов автора на наводящие вопросы выяснилось, что, видимо, требуется ссылка на документацию *apache*.

в частности на директивы [allow и deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#host) (в версиях *apache* < 2.4) и заменяющую их директиву [require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/access.html#host) (в версиях *apache* >= 2.4.

замечание: хотя использовать `allow/deny` можно и в более новых версиях, важно не смешивать эти директивы с более новой `require` в одной секции.

---

уточнение-дополнение по поводу именно проксирования:

[apache 2.2 Controlling access to your proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#access)

[apache 2.4 Controlling access to your proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#access)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно при обратном проксировании предполагается, что никто чужой не может обратиться к бэкенду - а потому он может доверять проставленным заголовкам. У вас же, я так понимаю, оба сервера видны снаружи.

Можно смотреть на адрес клиента - и доверять заголовкам только если это адрес первого сервера. Подмены адреса тут можно не опасаться - просто потому что если злоумышленник может подменить адрес отправителя пакета - то ему уже не надо подменять заголовки.

Но зачем вам вообще проксирование? Два разных адреса у одной и той же страницы - это плохо. Поставьте редирект.

Comment: Да, оба сервера видны снаружи, так удобней для тестирования и отладки. Так же я не могу поставить их на одну машину, так как они запущены под разными ОС. Проксирование требуется для свободного изменения адреса и порта второго сервера. Я отрабатываю эту технологию и мне нужно уметь работать с ней.

Answer (score 1):

Если второй сервер требуется открывать всему миру только при отладке - имеет смысл

1. Перенести сервер на нестандартный порт;
2. "Положить" в корень файл `robots.txt`, запрещающий индексацию всех страниц, чтобы защититься от раскрытия "тайного" сервера поисковикам через ваш же браузер (на основной сервер этот файл никак не повлияет - потому что окажется не в корне);
3. Настроить сетевую инфраструктуру таким образом, чтобы включать общий доступ к этому серверу и выключать обратно было довольно просто.

Comment: Про раскрытие фигня, нужны опции для апача, которыми блокируется доступ для всех ip адресов кроме адреса сервера. Теорию я знаю, мне нужны практические знания, а именно: как это реализовать на апаче.

Comment: Погодите, вам же надо это ограничение ставить на стороне самописного сервера, а не апача...

Comment: В любом случае, если нужно закрыть веб-сервер целиком - то его можно закрыть средствами системного файервола.

Comment: Я хочу посмотреть, как это реализовано в апаче, и вероятнее всего сделать так же, чтобы хотя бы на начальном этапе не устраивать бардак. Системный фаервол в windows это конечно смешно.

Comment: Ничего смешного, он существует и работает.

Comment: @mikelsv, посмотрите в моём [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429208/178576) ссылки на документацию про ограничение доступа вообще и к прокси-серверу в частности (в дополнении). ну а реализацию этих директив можно увидеть в [исходниках *apache*](http://www.apache.org/dev/version-control.html), благо это свободное программное обеспечение.